# Reverse Proxy using Raspbian and Apache

Tags: apache, gitlab, reverse-proxy

### Reverse Proxy using Raspian and Apache

I have a few machines running different applications on them. Recently I bought a Raspberry Pi 4, trying to make it to serve as a reverse proxy server for the applications. Let say I have three machines A, B, and C, where

A: Raspberry Pi 4, running Raspbian buster lite with Apache2 installed. IP: 192.168.1.2. I am trying to configure it into a reverse proxy server.

B: A VM running Ubuntu 18.04. IP: 192.168.1.3. Hosting a GitLab server.

C: A VM running Ubuntu 18.04. IP: 192.168.1.4. Hosting a RStudio Server.

I also have a domain name with ssl encrypted. Let say the domain name is `example.com`. As there are a few applications that I want to be routed by A, I want to make the url `example.com/gitlab` to be routed to B and `example.com/rstudio` to be routed to C.

With the code below stored in `A:/etc/apache2/sites-available/gitlab.conf`, I can route `example.com` to B. But it will affect the routing to C.

```sh
# Specify path for Logs
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade}     !=websocket
RewriteRule            /(.*)     http://192.168.1.3/(.*) [P,L]
ProxyPass              /         http://192.168.1.3/
ProxyPassReverse       /         http://192.168.1.3/
ProxyRequests off
```

I have also tried replace those `/` to `/gitlab/`. But it fails as, when I type in `example.com/gitlab`, the browser was redirected to `example.com/users/sign_in` rather than `example.com/gitlab/users/sign_in` as it should be. Please also refer to the script below

```sh
# Specify path for Logs
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
RewriteEngine on

# Following lines should open gitlab directly from the url
# Map gitlab to gitlab/
RedirectMatch ^/gitlab$ /gitlab/

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade}     !=websocket
RewriteRule              /gitlab/(.*)     http://192.168.1.3/(.*) [P,L]
ProxyPass                /gitlab/         http://192.168.1.3/
ProxyPassReverse         /gitlab/         http://192.168.1.3/

ProxyRequests off
```

How should I configure the apache to make this work? Many thanks!

Comment: You most probably need this https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/install/relative_url.html

Comment: @DusanBajic. Thanks, I have reach the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [DusanBajic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1145196/dusan-bajic), I have reached the solution.

### Configuration on GitLab Server

On the GitLab server, locate the line

```sh
external_url 'http://gitlab.example.com/'
```

from `gitlab.rb` in `/etc/gitlab/` and modify the line into

```sh
external_url 'http://gitlab.example.com/gitlab/'
```

Then run the following scripts

```sh
sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure
sudo gitlab-ctl restart
sudo reboot
```

Then you can access the GitLab via

```
http://localhost/gitlab/
```

but you may find it responding error 502. Just wait for a few minutes and try again.

### Configuration on Proxy Server

On the proxy server, create a file `gitlab.conf` in the directory `/etc/apache2/sites-available/` with the following lines

```sh
# Specify path for Logs
ErrorLog                ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog               ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log    combined
RewriteEngine           on

# Following lines should open gitlab directly from the url
# Map gitlab to gitlab/
RedirectMatch           ^/gitlab$              /gitlab/

RewriteCond             %{HTTP:Upgrade}         !=websocket
RewriteRule             /gitlab/(.*)           http://192.168.1.3/gitlab/(.*) [P,L]
ProxyPass               /gitlab/               http://192.168.1.3/gitlab/
ProxyPassReverse        /gitlab/               http://192.168.1.3/gitlab/
ProxyRequests           off
```

Then run the following scripts

```sh
sudo a2enmod proxy
sudo a2enmod proxy_http
sudo a2enmod proxy_html
sudo a2enmod proxy_wstunnel
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

and

```sh
sudo a2ensite gitlab.conf
sudo systemctl reload apache2
sudo service apache2 restart
```